# Add button is missing when I tried to Add a WebPart

Tags: web-part, publishing-page, wiki-pages

I have "People search results (Page Layout)" page  with Content Type = "Welcome Page". I need to drop another people search result web part on this page.

I can see the all web parts but Add button is missing. What to do?

Comment: try selecting it and hitting enter

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @BludBird: Selecting the WebPart and hitting the Enter Button on the keyboard did the magic. Thanks
Mahsun

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom master page for your search centre then it is probably messing up the layout.  Try switching to the standard minimal.master while you edit the page.  This should make sure the Add button reappears.  You can then switch back to your custom master page when complete.

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem a few days ago, my colleagues confirmed that the page layout was modified and the 'Add' button was push out of place. While waiting for them fo fix it, I use a trick:

- After choosing 'Categories' and 'Parts', click on the white space of
  'About the Part' section.
- Press 'Tab' a few times until the focus
  move to the 'Add' button, the button will appear again. You can click on it.